# Run time of Threadpool in c# .NET4.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, sorting, threadpool, stopwatch

Hi i want to measure the run time of a function in my code. i use threadpool for running that function.

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch w = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        w.Start();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(f));
        w.Stop();
        label1.Text = w.Elapsed.ToString();

f(){ //array.sort()}
```

The f() sort some numbers.

Example: for 60000000 numbers stopwatch shows:with threadpool 00:00:00.0003201 but performance whitout threading 00:00:06.8651903 ???

For 1000 numbers with threadpool 00:00:00.0001801 and whitout it 00:00:00.0011956 ???

Now i have some questions?

1.could threadpool decrease the run time or i made a mistake?

2.could stopwatch measure the run time of functions that run simultaneously?

Comment: Why are you measuring the amount of time it takes to ask the thread pool to eventually do something?

Comment: _"i want to measure the run time of a function in my code"_ - All you are doing is measuring the time it takes to **queue** an item via `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` **not** how long `f()` takes to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.could threadpool decrease the run time or i made a mistake?

Afraid you made a mistake.  `QueueUserWorkItem` returns immediately allowing the current thread to continue while the work is being done on a different thread.  Therefore `w.Stop();` is called immediately after the work begins.  It doesn't wait for the work item to complete.  So you effectively measured how long it takes just to add an item to the queue, not how long it actually takes to complete the work.

> 2.could stopwatch measure the run time of functions that run simultaneously?

You could start/stop the watch inside the function, or have a delegate function that is a proxy to the actual function.  This delegate could wrap the actual function/work with the start/stop calls and send the resulting time to where it needs to be logged to.

Answer (score 1):

With TreadPool, the elapsed time is only the time to queue the work item (not the time to execute it) because you don't wait for the end of the thread.

For your first question, you can increase performance using multiple threads, but in your code example, it change almost nothing.

For your second question, no, but maybe this NuGet package will help you: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MethodTimer.Fody/